Link between metric, symplectic and complex structures
I am trying to prove the following properties that link the metric ($g$) and the symplectic ($\omega$) forms with the complex structure ($J$):
$$J\text{ is orthogonal} \iff g(Jx,Jy)=g(x,y) \\ J \text{ is symplectic} \iff \omega(Jx,Jy)=\omega(x,y)$$
First one I try to prove by assuming  $JJ^T=\hat{\mathbb{I}}.$ Then by using the canonical form of the metric:
$$
g_{ij}=\varepsilon_i \delta_{ij} \ \ , \ \varepsilon_i=\pm1 \\
g(Je_i,Je_j)=J_i^jg_{jk}J_p^k=J_i^j\varepsilon_j\delta_{jk}J_p^k=\varepsilon_kJ_i^kJ_p^k
$$
And now this result should somehow be equal to $g_{ip}=\varepsilon_i\delta_{ip}$ and I can't seem to reduce it to this form.
And when it comes to the second one I start to doubt even my understanding on what is meant here by "orthogonal" since the only definition for a symplectic matrix I can think of is:
$$\omega=J\omega J^T$$
Which leads me to the idea that what is meant by "orthogonal" is analogical. But then those statements would be definitions. How is then possible for the complex structure to be symplectic or not symplectic when its canonical form is unique? Am I misunderstanding something about the coordinate systems? Can you help me with the clarification of those terms and the derivations?

Well for orthogonal specifically I'm using the standard $AA^T=\hat{\mathbb{I}}$ but that's the thing. When I get to the symplectic part of it i can't think of anything else than what I've written which makes me believe by "orthogonal" it is meant $AgA^T=g$. I guess my question is - the symplectic form  $\omega$ and the complex structure $J$ have only one canonical form, so why the condition? Isn't it the case that $J$ is either always or never symplectic?

Differential geometry is often "parameterised linear algebra". It's not useful to try to work things out in coordinates when you do not yet grasp the linear algebraic concepts (in my view) because it adds an unnecessary layer of complications.
Let $V$ be any real vector space (let's say of dimension $2n$). Let $B:V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$ be any non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$. It doesn't matter whether $B$ is symmetric or skew-symmetric or positive definite. Let $M:\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(L,L)\to\text{Mat}(2n\times 2n,\mathbb{R})$ denote the map which sends a linear transformation to its matrix representation (under some choice of basis), and let $B$ denote the matrix representation of the bilinear form $B$. That is, $B(v,w)=v^T Bw$. Then there is a bijective correspondence between linear transformations $L\in\text{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(L,L)$ such that $L^*B=B$ and matrices $M(L)\in\text{Mat}(2n\times 2n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $M(L)^TB M(L)=B$. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
B(v,w)=B(Lv,Lw)\quad\forall v,w\in V\iff \\(M(L)v)^TB(M(L)w)=v^TM(L)^TBM(L)w\quad\forall v,w\in V \iff \\M(L)^TBM(L)=B
\end{align*}
We can say that such linear transformations $L$ are orthogonal w.r.t. $B$. Now, if $g$ is symmetric and positive definite, then the equation can be reduced to $M(L)^TM(L)=I_{2n\times 2n}$ because you can find a basis in which $B$ is the identity matrix (you do have to choose such a basis!). If $B$ represents a symplectic form, then the equation is commonly written as $\omega= L^T\omega L$ (notice that the map from linear transformations to matrices isn't explicit anymore). Specifically, an almost complex structure $J:V\to V$, which is just a very specific case of this, is "symplectic" (i.e. preserves $\omega$, i.e. is orthogonal w.r.t. $\omega$), if $\omega = J^T\omega J$ in terms of matrices, because this is the equivalent of $\omega(Jv,Jw)=\omega(v,w)$ for all $v,w\in V$. So what you've written down seems, to me, like a tautology. It's just whether you choose to represent the objects as linear transformations, or as matrices.
